# What's the point in arp -g?

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, arp

I typed `arp` into Windows CMD and it gave me the options as to what I can do with it.

It gave me `arp -a` (then gave details) and then it showed `arp -g` which says 'same as `-a`'

So what's the point of having two options that do the exactly the same thing? why not deprecate `-g` and keep `-a` or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the `-g` remains for compatibility with certain older versions.

Note that *arp* and various other tools were originally imported from BSD, along with the entire TCP/IP stack. The BSD *arp* command uses `-a`. (So does the SunOS one, apparently.)

It is possible that either the `-a` in Windows *arp* was accidentally changed to `-g`, then changed back, or that some other operating system used `arp -g` for the same task.